# How to retrieve data from a table cell in angular 2

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2. I try to retrieve data from a table cell. Is there an Angular 2 way to do this?

I tried to do like this, but I got `undefined` value.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td (click)="getValue($event)">John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>Moe</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

getValue(event:any) {
    let value = event.target.value;
    console.log("value", value);
}
```

Comment: Can you please try to figure out what `target` is? like `console.log(event.target.outerHTML)`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, hmm.. like this one I got `<td _ngcontent-bjt-9="">John</td>`, the value **John** is already there, but when I tried to use `event.target.value` or `event.target.outerHTML`. Then becomes `undefined`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use instead

```
let value = event.target.innerText;
```

or

```
let value = event.target.innerHTML;
```

The `<td>` doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: Thanks! `event.target.innerHTML` works, `event.target.text` does not work.

Comment: @HongboMiao he meant `innerText`